Recognize blurred characters?
OCR failed on this in spite of my attempts to enhance it.  Can someone type a text version?

I suppose it’s a representation of the surname "Groleau" but maybe I got the order wrong.  When my late father was teaching English in Guangzhou, they gave him a name seal:

It’s French Canadian, pronounced Grow Low but unfamiliar English speakers typically assume Grow Loo.  If the person creating it only saw the spelling, he/she might have assumed Grow Lei: 格洛雷 géluòléi.  But that’s assuming it’s strictly phonetic; perhaps they tried to make some kind of semantic statement.

How low would a Groleau grow if a Groleau could grow low?

格洛雷 is derived from the surname “groleau”, i edited the answer, read again, please

well, with image of the whole seal, it should be read as:
r . j 格洛雷 (groleau)
格 —> gaak3,
洛 -> lok3
errrr, the “r” & “l” was interchanged, “lo” pronounce quite similar as “ro” in cantonese
雷-> lui4
rightmost may be: “洛”, though the left component is just half 
https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk//Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%B4%9B
centre one: “格”
https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk//Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%A0%BC
leftmost is: “雷”
< https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk//Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E9%9B%B7>


I don't think the order of the characters makes sense. Maybe 雷 is a representation of the first name instead, and 格洛 is just an abbreviation of the surname.

@dROOOze 格 —> gaak3, 雷-> lui4; the best i can guess from “groleau”  of course, your suggestion is more natural, make more sense

Based on your answer, I added information to the question.

I know that Guangzhou is more a Cantonese region, but doesn't the 普通話 pronunciation, géluòléi , come closer?  It still surprises me for the last character to be in the upper right.

@伟思礼 “géluòléi , come closer? ” well, imo, no 洛 lok3, chop the k3, lo -> ro  luò -> ruò, most would get the character “若”

I doubt "come closer" has any connection.  More likely a phonetic approximation of the name "Groleau."  géluò to me sounds more like "Gro" than does gaklok which would require dropping 'k' twice.  But either is reasonable.

It is read "R.J 格雷洛" (Groleau)
格雷洛 (Groleau)
格雷洛 (Groleau)
格雷洛 (Groleau)
Groleau is a French name, so, it is a French--> Cantonese transiteration
